# Infinite loop while deploy function in region europe-west3

Tags: google-cloud-functions

From yesterday I can`t update existed function. I`m trying to create new one from the same code and have same infinite loop.

```bash
$ gcloud functions deploy --gen2 --runtime=go120 --region=europe-west3 --trigger-http --allow-unauthenticated --entry-point=HelloHTTP --memory=128Mi --timeout=120s --service-account=***@appspot.gserviceaccount.com SomeName
Preparing function...done.                                                                                                                                                                                                      
⠛ Deploying function...                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  ✓ [Build] Logs are available at [https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/builds;region=europe-west3/uuid?project=projectid]                                                           
  ⠛ [Service] Creating Cloud Run service...                                                                                                                                                                                     
  . [ArtifactRegistry]                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  . [Healthcheck]                                                                                                                                                                                                               
  . [Triggercheck]
```

I trying update existed function with the same code and command, then I trying create new function with the same code

Finded in logs:
`Unable to create 0 instances for "***2-00001-sif" because there are already 0 in this region.`

**UPD**: if i change `--region=europe-west3` to something else, for example `--region=europe-west2` - everything ok

**UPD2**: same problem in web interface. I tryed deploy default function. Step 1 finished - Creating build. Step 2 was working very long time - Creating Cloud Run service, and did not completed

Comment: Please do not post images of plaintext as [they are not appropriate on StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3784008). Please copy and paste plaintext into your question.

Answer (score 0):

The availability of resources in the `europe-west3` region for Cloud Functions appears to be limited. Like a workaround, you can try deploying your function to a separate area, like you have indicated.

You can also check the Cloud Functions quota for the `europe-west3` region to see if there are any limits that might be causing the issue. To view the quota, you can use the following command:

```
gcloud compute regions describe europe-west3 --project=<your-project-id>
```

This will give you information about the quota for the region, such as the number of CPUs, memory, and other resources that are available.

If you continue to experience the issue, you can reach out to [Google Cloud support](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub) for further assistance.